# Explanation for PyDev icons?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I just installed eclipse + pydev for Python development.

Is there any explanation for the meaning of the pretty icons?

[image]

Comment: Just a moment people: this falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers" so **it's not off-topic**.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "What do the icons in Eclipse mean?" The question is about PyDev Icons and the referenced question is about the JDT icons. The Icon sets are different and PyDev does not provide an in-app help that explains them.